# How to use PrimeNg Chart of Width and Height?

Tags: chart.js, primeng

How can i use width and height for PrimeNg Chart?

```
 <p-chart type="bar" width="400" height="400" [data]="data"></p-chart>
```

There is no effect when i use width and height.Please let me know how to use Chart of width and height.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/4gjuvp/chartjs_canvas_height_width_ignored/

According to that link you have to set two options for the chart:

```
<p-chart type="bar" width="400" height="400" [data]="data" [options]="options"></p-chart>
```

And in your Typescript Code:

```
options = {
  responsive: false,
  maintainAspectRatio: false
};
```

Answer (score 8):

[Looking over the source code](https://github.com/TekSiDoT/primeng/blob/master/components/chart/chart.ts), p-chart takes width and height as component inputs, so putting them in [] should do the trick:

```
<p-chart type="bar" [width]="400" [height]="400" [data]="data"></p-chart>
```